# Dynamically set shared dataset path in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I'm having one SSRS report, which is currently using shared dataset which inside the same report folder. Shared Data-set is in the same folder.

Path of Shared Dataset is `win2008/Reports/ABC/sharedDataset.rsd`

Now on Production site, report folder name will be the same but Shared Dataset path may not exist.

**For example:** In "win2008/Reports/ABC/sharedDataset.rsd" - **win2008** may not be there so dataset error comes.

> The report server cannot process the report. The reference for the
>   shared dataset 'rptDs' is not valid. (rsInvalidDataSetReference)

*Can anyone please help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 2):

There is no way around this.  You need to either open up the report on your production environment and add the shared dataset again or the more thorough and advised solution, is to have your datasets held in a folder structure that is the same on both servers.

In general, if you are moving shared datasets around with the report you may as well be embedding them.  Create a folder in the Home folder called `Datasets` and then put them all there, organised into various folders as you require.  Keep that folder structure the same on your Dev and Prod environment and you won't have this problem again.

Comment: I understand this solution but can't we directly do with catalog table or something like this?

Comment: @pedram  No.  The Shared Dataset is referenced directly in the report definition.  The only way to change where it is looking is to edit the report either in Report Builder/Visual Studio or in the .rdl XML directly.